# How to convert a list of tuples to string

Tags: python, string, list, tuples

How do I convert a list of tuples to string.
Please see the case below

Given Format:

```
[(a,b),(c,d)]
```

What I got:

Code:

```
[i for sub in tagged_in for i in sub]
tagged_in = [(a,b),(c,d)]
#Result = 'a,b,c,d'
```

Required Format:

```
'a-b,c-d'
```

Can someone please update my code to get the required format

Answer (score 6):

You can simply use the [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method of string objects:

```
>>> v = [("a","b"),("c","d")]
>>> ",".join(map("-".join,v))
'a-b,c-d'
```

***Edit:*** As pointed out by @MSeifert using list-comprehension is also possible:

```
>>> v= [("a","b"),("c","d")]
>>> ",".join(["-".join(tup) for tup in v])
'a-b,c-d'
```

While generators are generally the better choice there are some python functions (like `str.join` and `sorted`) that work better with lists. If performance is a concern it might therefore be preferable to use list-comprehension in this case:

```
>>> setup = 'v = [("a","b"),("c","d")]'
>>> repeat('",".join(map("-".join,v))',setup=setup)
[1.0896376324927814, 1.094142565225468, 1.0857250774588465]
>>> repeat('",".join(["-".join(tup) for tup in v])',setup=setup)
[0.8851533486462131, 0.8982919691165989, 0.9031148129180337]
```

Answer (score 3):

I generally like comprehensions more than `map`-approaches:

```
>>> tagged_in = [('a','b'),('c','d')]
>>> ','.join(['-'.join(tup) for tup in tagged_in])
'a-b,c-d'
```

However this is totally equivalent to the answer of @JonathanvonSchroeder. Just instead of `map` this is using a list-comprehension because `str.join` converts the arguments to a sequence no matter what - so this might even be a bit faster.

Comment: My philosophy, why go through the expense of a list comprehension when a generator expression (remove the `[ ]`) would do... :) Then it would really be equivalent to @JonathanvonSchroeder.

Comment: @AChampion Because [`str.join` needs a sequence](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/403ccddb9598bac6e0e6db4ba5aa2fe494512a98/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L9876). When you pass it a generator it's slower because it has to cast it to a sequence itself! Actually I felt bad to post that answer (because it's so similar) but whenever I see someone using a generator in `str.join` or `sorted` one does include unnecessary overhead. And it doesn't hurt to point that out whenever possible (given that you responded to the answer the effort wasn't in vein!). :)

Comment: @MSeifert Thanks - I wasn't aware of this aspect. How unfortunate that str.join can't work directly with the generator. Is it ok if add your input to my answer (with a small benchmark to illustrate the point)?

Comment: Hmm, for a random string of 1000000 letters I get a negligible difference in speed  `1 loop, best of 3: 998 ms per loop` vs `1 loop, best of 3: 1.03 s per loop` but obviously a big difference in memory. Will need to look into this more.

Comment: `timeit()` gave me `1.17` (for the `map`-based solution) vs `0.97` for the list-comprehension.

Comment: @JonathanvonSchroeder I already borrowed from your answer, so of course: feel free to include parts of the answer and a benchmark :)

Comment: @AChampion There is no difference in memory because it's converted to sequence inside `str.join`! And even with builtin-functions (where the `map` generator could skip the python layer entirely) it's generally not faster. `string = 'a'*1000000; %timeit ','.join(map(str.upper, string)); %timeit ','.join([a.upper() for a in string])` there the list-comprehension is only slightly faster but when you try it with python-functions the list comprehension will be a lot faster. Note that this is only true for some functions like `str.join` or `sorted`, otherwise generators are most of the times better.

Comment: @MSeifert - I have added your suggestion. If you have anything to add / clarify feel free to edit my answer.